# Adhesive tape: in the direction of expected stress or perpendicular to it?

Tags: adhesive

I have used some pieces of double-sided adhesive tape to fix a doormat on laminate flooring. The expected stress for this mat is from and towards the door; most people scrub their shoes perpendicular to the door.

Of course, more tape will always reduce the chance the mat will eventually be removed from its place by normal usage, but I was wondering: given a limited supply of tape, what is the best way to position them? I guess at least one piece of tape in each corner, but does their orientation (along or perpendicular to the expected stress, or even at a 45 degree angle) matter at all?

Answer (score 1):

Best solution I have seen is to make a recess and drop the mat in the recess.

Allows the mat to be taken out and cleaned, also no sticky residue.

[image]

source : https://www.amazon.co.uk/Stainless-Matwell-Entrance-Surround-Insert/dp/B00PK4LNKM

Comment: Sure, that would work for this particular job, but I am mostly interested in the general case. Or is that too theoretical for DIY.SE?

Comment: I tried once horizontal, vertical, diagonal - all come unstuck and removing the residue is a pia - but you're welcome to take your theory and prove it for yourself.